# UART/UDP communication in c++ with integers

Tags: c++, udp, uart

I would like to ask about UDP and UART communication in c++. I am using libraries sys/socket.h, fcntl.h (for uart) and netinet/in.h for udp, but instead of string I would like to send an array of ints, but somehow I am getting 0 every time I send anything. Is there a problem with libraries? Would you recommend me different ones or should I be trying to fix my code?

My code looks like this, I do not think there are any mistakes regarding it as it is all the libraries.

```
void UDP::send_data(uint8_t data[]) const {
    sendto(udp, data, sizeof(data), MSG_CONFIRM, 
          (const struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, len);
}

void UART::send_data(uint8_t data[]) const {
    write(uart, data, sizeof(data));
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Your sizes are wrong.

`uint8_t data[]` as a function parameter gets its type adjusted to `uint8_t*` and `sizeof` gives you the size of a pointer, which is not what you wanted.